# Is there a way to block recipients in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, gmail-filters

I'm not looking to block *senders*, I'm looking to block *recipients*.  For instance, I've occasionally hit Reply and written an email to an address of the type `do-not-reply@domain.com`, `no-reply@domain.com`, or `bounces@domain.com`, and then wondered why I never got a response, only to see that they require responses through a web form or something.

There are also some addresses who might be CC'ed on a message, but who I would never want to reply to, for instance.

I'd like to make a filter for addresses like this, so that if I try to send to them, it either aborts and moves it to the Drafts folder, or it gets redirected to myself, etc.

Comment: How about a label ("dev/null" perhaps), using a high-contrast color, to which all inbound mail from these sorts of addresses would get added to? It's not blocking, but it would probably get your attention.

Comment: I've once accidentally misspelled someone's email address and now gmail always offers the wrong address first, I also want to block recipients!

Comment: @domotorp I did that too, so I renamed that new contact to "NOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"

Answer (score 3):

Filters apply to incoming mail, not outgoing. So as of now - you can't do anything to prevent yourself from replying back to these.

The closest you can do is create a label titled "do-not-reply-to-these-mails" which is bright red in colour as a reminder

Answer (score 1):

You could also write a [time triggered](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#TimeTriggers) google apps script that checks the recipients of recently sent messages and send you back a warning message if there is any on your 'blacklist'. This solution, however, wouldn't stop you from sending messages.

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470622/accessing-sent-email-in-google-apps-script) of a script accessing sent emails.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the G-Suite you can create a content compliance rule and reject any email with specific text in the headers including an email address.

Navigate here: 
Apps -> G Suite -> Settings for Gmail -> Advanced settings

And then create a content compliance rule like this:

Email messages to affect -> (Outbound, Internal - sending)

If the above expressions match, do the following -> reject

Here is the google help doc:
[Set up rules for content compliance](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346934?hl=en)